# using Android Log methods 

Tags: android

I've seen many posts on here advising the use of logcat.  However, whenever I try and do this by replacing `e.printStackTrace()` with `Log.e(....,....,e)` I get a syntax error.

So how do you write out `Log.e(....,....,e)`?

Thanks!

Comment: While others have posted the answer to your exact question, I would like to point out that generally what people are referring to is the error log which is created automatically. If you go to log cat and click the red "E" circle in the upper right hand corner you will have only errors. As long as you look shortly after the crash you should see a complete stack trace of the error no work on your behalf!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Log.e(TAG, "My message", e);
```

or

```
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
```

Where `TAG` is a String you can define yourself. Usually this is the same in all messages, so you can filter the messages on this tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
Log.e("tag", "msg", exception);
```

Comment: would writing "e" be the same as "exception"?

Comment: Yes, it depends how you defined your exception. Ex: `catch (Exception e) { Log.e("tag", "msg", e);}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage);
```

Hope this helps. :)

EDIT:

Corrections

Comment: Had a mistype - I fixed it. :)